# Could not find configuration node: settings/setting[@name='MediaFolder']/@value

Tags: configuration

We are upgrading from sitecore 7.2 website to the latest 8.2 update 3. and the website is giving this error - Could not find configuration node: `settings/setting[@name='MediaFolder']/@value`.

Is there any fix?

References to MediaFolder word in Configuration:[image: search results]

Stack Trace:

> [InvalidOperationException: Could not find configuration node: settings/setting[@name='MediaFolder']/@value]
>      Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.GetConfigNode(String xpath, Boolean assert) +525
>      Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(String configPath, String[] parameters, Boolean assert) +273
>      Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateFromReference(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert) +170
>      Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert, IFactoryHelper helper) +116
>      Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert) +72
>      Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(String configPath, String[] parameters, Boolean assert) +615
>      Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.GetString(String configPath, Boolean assert) +57
>      Sitecore.IO.FileWatcher..ctor(String configReference) +235
>
> [TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
>      System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck) +0
>      System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +197
>      System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic) +105
>      System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +1484
>      System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes) +289
>      System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture) +27
>      System.Web.HttpRuntime.CreateNonPublicInstance(Type type, Object[] args) +79
>      System.Web.HttpApplication.BuildIntegratedModuleCollection(List`1 moduleList) +222
>      System.Web.HttpApplication.GetModuleCollection(IntPtr appContext) +1086
>      System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +123
>      System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +169
>      System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +396
>      System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +333
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
>      System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +525
>      System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +124
>      System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +700

Comment: This could be the same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40902784/could-not-find-configuration-node-settings-settingname-mediafolder-value - if there are any syntax errors in any of the other config files, it can cause strange error messages.

Comment: Open the ShowConfig page and see if it opens. If not, then you have an issue with the xml syntax. Might be that a tag is not well-formed or closed or due to comment tag

Comment: there were no xml validation errors to fix in sitecore.contentsearch.config. and can't review showconfig.aspx yet because /sitecore website fails to load with same error. will try to validate all xml files.

Comment: @vijaymajeti it is not necessary the `sitecore.contentsearch.config` file which is causing the issue. It may be other files since with Sitecore 8.x, most config files have changed

Comment: @HishaamNamooya The error goes away, if i hard code the value '/upload' in the /watchers/media/folder setting instead of the xpath reference to another setting item within same file. And /sitecore showconfig all load fine as well. So, xpath resolution failure seems to be  blocking the website to load (sitecore bug?)

Comment: @vijaymajeti, no this is not a Sitecore bug. Sitecore cannot resolve the `@value`. Check if you had override the value of the mediaUpload variable from the showconfig

Comment: @HishaamNamooya We didn't override the MediaFolder setting. ShowConfig.aspx shows <sc.variable name="mediaFolder" value="/upload"/> and no other mediaFolder references

Comment: Thank you @HishaamNamooya. You are correct. There was an extraneous character in one of our sitecore config files and it caused above xpath to not evaluate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As specified in the comment, this is not a Sitecore bug. The reason of this issue is that, Sitecore cannot evaluate the `@value` because

1. Issue with the xml syntax where the xml is not well formed.
2. Check for special characters.
3. You can have overridden the value of the MediaFolder setting.

Based on your provided comment, for your issue, it was due to the 2nd point. Special characters.

Comment: it is because of special characters in config file